# how many times and index i appears in the list of ranges

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of ranges of Length N,  where start and end are inclusive in the range     [(5,7),(1,4),(2,3),(6,8),(3,5)]

and given any number K , lets say K=8

in an array of length K+1 find how many times each index is contained within a range in the List

lets say K=8, we will have an array (arr) from index 0 to index 8

arr[0]=0;
arr[1]=1; {1 is only contained in (1,4)} 
arr[2]=2; {2 is contained in (1,4) (2,3) } 
arr[3]=3; {3 is contained in (1,4) (2,3) (3,5) } 
arr[4]=2; {4 is contained in (1,4) (3,5)} 
arr[5]=2; {5 is contained in (3,5) (5,7)} 
arr[6]=2; {6 is contained in (5,7) (6,8)} 
arr[7]=2; {7 is contained in (5,7) (6,8)} 
arr[8]=1; {8 is contained in (6,8)}

I am looking for a O(N+K) solution

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I am using python. But how does language matter in this case ? Its an algorithm right ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do as follows in JS. It's not O(n+k) but worst case O(nk).

```js
function nToIndices(d,n){
  return d.reduce(function(p,c){
                    for (var i = c[0]; i <= c[1] && i <= n; i++){
                      p[i] !== undefined ? p[i].push(c) : p[i] = [c];
                    }
                    return p;
                  },[[0]]);
}
var arr = [[5,7],[1,4],[2,3],[6,8],[3,5]];
console.log(JSON.stringify(nToIndices(arr,8)));
```